# Error occurred while installing rmagick

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redmine

I'm getting following error while trying to install Redmine on Windows Server 2008 R2.

```
C:\Ruby\Apps\Redmine>rake db:migrate
←[31mCould not find gem 'rmagick (>= 2.0.0) x86-mingw32' in the gems available o
n this machine.←[0m
←[33mRun `bundle install` to install missing gems.←[0m

C:\Ruby\Apps\Redmine>bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.......
Using rake (0.9.2.2)
Using i18n (0.6.1)
Using multi_json (1.3.6)
Using activesupport (3.2.8)
Using builder (3.0.0)
Using activemodel (3.2.8)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using journey (1.0.4)
Using rack (1.4.1)
Using rack-cache (1.2)
Using rack-test (0.6.2)
Using hike (1.2.1)
Using tilt (1.3.3)
Using sprockets (2.1.3)
Using actionpack (3.2.8)
Using mime-types (1.19)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.10)
Using mail (2.4.4)
Using actionmailer (3.2.8)
Using arel (3.0.2)
Using tzinfo (0.3.33)
Using activerecord (3.2.8)
Using activeresource (3.2.8)
Using bundler (1.2.1)
Using coderay (1.0.7)
Using fastercsv (1.5.5)
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2)
Using json (1.7.5)
Using rdoc (3.12)
Using thor (0.16.0)
Using railties (3.2.8)
Using jquery-rails (2.0.3)
Using metaclass (0.0.1)
Using mocha (0.12.3)
Using mysql (2.8.1)
Using net-ldap (0.3.1)
Using pg (0.14.1)
Using ruby-openid (2.1.8)
Using rack-openid (1.3.1)
Using rails (3.2.8)
Installing rmagick (2.13.1) with native extensions
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
.

        C:/Ruby187/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
Invalid drive specification.
Unable to get ImageMagick version
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby187/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.1
3.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/g
em_make.out
An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.13.1), and Bundler cannot continue
.
Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.13.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

---

On trying to install rmagick using this gem install rmagick -v '2.13.1'

I'm getting this error...

```
C:\Ruby\Apps\Redmine>gem install rmagick -v 2.13.1
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/Ruby187/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
Invalid drive specification.
Unable to get ImageMagick version
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby187/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.1
3.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/g
em_make.out
```

Comment: do you have devkit installed in your path?

Comment: Yes, devkit is installed. But don't know about its path? Pls explain.

Comment: do on your command  prompt `set PATH=%DEVKIT_HOME%\bin;%PATH%` before running `gem install rmagick` from same terminal. This is assuming your `DEVKIT_HOME` variable resolves to your devkit installation directory

Comment: My path to devkit is c:\Ruby187\devkit, pls advise.

Comment: so just prepend it to your path I.e. `set PATH=c:\ruby187\devkit\bin;%PATH%` and then run `gem install rmagick` from same terminal

Comment: this doesn't work, still same error...

Comment: How to close this question, as this isn't solved, and I don't want to keep it open..

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this:

```
apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
gem install rmagick
```

Comment: From comments, it appeared to work for others.. Note that I have switched to a different solution altogether so can't say that whether it works for me or not! But as it worked for others, I'm accepting this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Imagemagick first? http://www.imagemagick.org

Actually, see : [Won't Let Me Install Gem in Ruby Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972321/wont-let-me-install-gem-in-ruby-prompt)

Comment: Yes, still it doesn't work. One thing I noticed is ROR sucks, there isn't proper documentation on anything, and even after spending countless hours in last two days, it throws one error after another and finally I've decided to use Bitnami installer rather then installing it as per instruction.

Answer (score 0):

**sudo apt-get install libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev**

and after run bundle install