# rmagick install extconf.rb error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rmagick, extconf.rb

Hi I'm trying to install `rmagick` for like 10 hours, the frustration is immense..

So here follows:

```
c:\>ruby -v
ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [i386-mingw32]

c:\>rails --version
Rails 5.0.0

c:\>gem --version
2.4.5.1
```

---

```
c:\Ruby22\bin>convert -version
Invalid drive specification.

c:\ImageMagick-6.9.5-Q16>convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.5-3 Q16 x86 2016-07-22 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2015 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Visual C++: 180040629
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo flif freetype jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr openexr pa
ngocairo png ps rsvg tiff webp xml zlib
```

and finally when im trying to install (i also have DevKit)

```
c:\Ruby22>gem install rmagick -- --with-opt-dir=c:\ImageMagick-6.9.5-Q16
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions with: '--with-opt-dir=c:\ImageMagick-6.9.5-Q16'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby22/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160725-4412-1q7n0st.rb extconf.rb --wi
th-opt-dir=c:\ImageMagick-6.9.5-Q16
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby22/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
extconf.rb:110:in ``': No such file or directory - identify -version (Errno::ENO
ENT)
        from extconf.rb:110:in `configure_compile_options'
        from extconf.rb:16:in `initialize'
        from extconf.rb:517:in `new'
        from extconf.rb:517:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rmagick-2.
15.4 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.2.0/rma
gick-2.15.4/gem_make.out
```

I've tried many many solutions , nothing works , just keep getting this error.

I messed with %PATH% ,tried different versions , read all the instructions , tried in 2 different machines. It seems impossible for me..

the suggested duplicate offers obsolete links that lead nowhere, even if it is a duplicate of an answered question , that answer is not up to date and offers no good.  I truly wish that could help , but i came across that answer a while ago...

Comment: It seems a mistake in the path `--with-opt-dir=c:\ImageMagick-6.9.5-Q16`
Just an opinion: I recommend you change OS for avoiding such nondeterministic errors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Won't Let Me Install Gem in Ruby Prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972321/wont-let-me-install-gem-in-ruby-prompt)

Comment: umm there's not even a file called like that anymore, maybe what you say about windows .. maybe i should go to ubuntu.. but darn this installation is so broken ...  and about the path , i've seen so many write it this way , it's just the way gem wants it :S

Comment: Have you seen [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972321/wont-let-me-install-gem-in-ruby-prompt)?

Comment: yes but sadly there's no file in there :S